# Error in Adding multiple custom tabs on product view page

Tags: magento2, tabs

I want to add two new custom tabs on product view page first one is added but when i add second tab i got error.
**"product.category" is not a child of "product.info.details". Resolve the issue and try again.**

> catalog_product_views.xml

```
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
      <block class="vendor\Module\Block\BlockName"
        name="products.tab"
        template="Vendor_Module::first.phtml"
        group="detailed_info">
          <arguments>
              <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom tab 1</argument>
                      <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">200</argument>
          </arguments>
      </block>
       <block class="vendor\Module\Block\BlockName"
        name="product.category"
        as="additional"
        after="products.tab"
        template="Vendor_Module::second.phtml"
        group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom tab2</argument>
                    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">220</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
  </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `after="products.tab"`.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
      <block class="vendor\Module\Block\BlockName"
        name="products.tab"
        template="Vendor_Module::first.phtml"
        group="detailed_info">
          <arguments>
              <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom tab 1</argument>
                      <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">200</argument>
          </arguments>
      </block>
       <block class="vendor\Module\Block\BlockName"
        name="product.category"
        as="additional"
        template="Vendor_Module::second.phtml"
        group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom tab2</argument>
                    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">220</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
  </referenceBlock>
```